# How to avoid Tattling

Tags: personal-practice, ethics, community, mental-factors, commentary

Hurting someone physically, Mentally, Verbally is a sin according to Buddhism. As I believe no matter we love or hate each other, anyhow we don't have any ownership of any others lives.

1. So how about **Gossiping** or the **tattling** about others lives ?
2. How does Buddhism explain ***specifically*** about TATTLING ??
3. How one should practice not to Gossip about others lives ?
4. In the other way how one should practice to face others Gossiping about
   himself/herself ?

Comment: **Please note:** I'm here referring gossiping about personal life, Not in business environment.

Comment: Abstain from people who are not in the sphere of [kalyanamitta](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/kalyanamittata_en.html) which requires to become one by one self. [heaven and hell](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2135.0.html#footlink21) even approve and disapprove.

Comment: but unfortunately we have to deal with the non-kalyanamitta too in our day to day life. Dealing with them is very hard though have understanding of them. :(

Comment: Why is it hard not to response if people like to talk this or that?

Comment: yes that's hard. And now I think that's because of our attention on them. If we can improve our attention on some meaningful thing by practicing **samatha meditation**, then I think we can avoid lots of such situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how about Gossiping or the tattling about others lives ?

You are wasting your time and others time. Talk that is productive towards betterment of oneself, which lacks proper reasoning (mud slinging), if you are monk not connected with the goal, the pratice, the Dhamma or Vinaya.

> How does Buddhism explain specifically about TATTLING ??

If it is to divide people then it is not right speech. Also it should not be with malice, but say you are a witness of a wrong doing then perhaps might have a social or legal or moral obligation to report it but even this case some aversion arises as you are averse to the fact that something does not fall to your moral, social or legal idea but in society, work and as a householder you have to do these things sometimes.

> How one should practice not to Gossip about others lives ?

If it can be an example to others then maybe it is OK. Otherwise change the topic to something productive or something you can learn from.

> In the other way how one should practice to face others Gossiping about himself/herself ?

If you can learn something from it then try to. Sometimes in Business and Work situations you have to promote or market yourself and also engage in chatting to a maintain cordial relationships. This is not unproductive endeavour or killing time by chatting.

Even in a personal situation you what you have to see if the chatting is directed at achieving something productive to yourself and listeners. Does it help you understand something better. Is there something listener can lean by a situation some one else has been in. If it is wasting time try changing the topic or move on it it is not inappropriate or rude. For a householder trying to build relationships, networking and friendships is productive and endeavor, even at a personal level, hence may not be idle chatter.

Comment: Thank You Sir for your ideas :) 
_regarding last question:-_ I'm expecting an answer regarding personal life, Not in professional (Business) environment please.

Comment: I edited my answer see if the additions address your question